# How can i provide two different fonts to a text based on the current Locale in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create an app that will support two languages, the first one is English and the second one is the Kurdish language which uses letters that are similar to Arabic letters (ا،ب،ج). I want to give a text a specific font based on the selected locale of the app, for example, if the selected language is English I want the app to have the default font supplied by apple and if the locale is Kurdish I will supply my custom font. I know how to load a custom font and assign it individually to a specific text but I want to create some sort of a modifier that will handle the locality logic and apply the appropriate font based on the locale instead of checking for the locale in every text I create. here is a snippet code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```swift
Text("Test")
   .font(Font.myTitle())
```

Text will be "test" in English and will be "تێست" Kurdish.

I tried to extend the font to read from the environment variable but I guess I was wrong since environment variables are available only in views. here is what I tried in the extension:

```swift
extension Font{
    public static func myTitle() -> Font{
        @Environment(\.locale) var locale: Locale
        let isKurdish = locale.identifier == "ku"
        if(isKurdish) {
            return Font.custom("rabar_013", size: 30)
        }
        return Font.title
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an extension on `Font` you can create your own `ViewModifier` that will have access to the `Environment`.

Something like this should do it.

```
struct LanguageTitleModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.locale) private var locale

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(font)
    }

    private var font: Font {
        let isKurdish = locale.identifier == "ku"
        if isKurdish {
            return Font.custom("rabar_013", size: 30)
        } else {
            return Font.title
        }
    }
}
```

You can then create a helper extension on `View` so that it is easier to use.

```
extension View {
    func languageTitle() -> some View {
        self.modifier(LanguageTitleModifier())
    }
}
```

You then use it in the following way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .languageTitle()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's effectively the same solution as mine the only difference is that you have decided to pass in an additional parameter which wasn't present in the question

Comment: yes, of course. but i think `Font.myTitle()` is an argument for `.font()` isn't it ?